# How do I open this flush mounted light fixture?

Tags: ceiling, light

Having trouble opening this light fixture to replace bulbs.  The blue/white glass appear to be one piece.  No visible screws or on base.  I tried twisting it open, but whoever installed the box behind it did a poor job (old work box) and now one of the butterfly wings is collapsed and it’s half-falling out of the wall.  I need to take it apart to re-deploy the old box wing, but right now I can’t open it at all.  It’s probably 20 years old.

Any suggestions?

[image: Pic 1]

[image: Pic 2]

Comment: Its hard to tell, but could you possibly pull it completely out of the ceiling? Might damage your hole, but you need to redo the box anyway. Once out of the ceiling you might be able to see on the back side better....just make sure to remove power from the circuit when doing this.